# Stop celery worker when something is going wrong

Tags: python, celery

How can i stop celery from code, when something is going wrong? For example redis or database is down.

For example i can stop connect if init function get exception

```
@stop_if_error
@signals.worker_process_init.connect
def init_method(*_, **_):
    #some init code
```

But how can stop if worker job in progress and exception has come?

Comment: please provide some details about the `stop_if_error` decorator, where is it coming from? could not find it in celery docs

Comment: @Greenev it's custom decorator, not in celery part.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Celery only to retry N times if the broker (Redis if I understood well) is down. About the database you mentioned - I assume you mean result-backend? If you do, then it depends on your use case. It is not critical if result-backend does not work.

We do not do any checks, instead we make sure broker and result-backend are highly-available (Redis cluster for an example).

Answer (score 0):

It's better late than never. I hope this will help you

```py
import celery.exceptions
import celery.signals

# Your code...

@celery.signals.worker_init.connect
def worker_init(*_, **__) -> None:
    try:
        pass  # some init code
    except Exception as e:
        raise celery.exceptions.WorkerShutdown() from e

    return None
```